# Difference between CALCULATE(m, x=red) vs CALCULATE(m, KEEPFILTERS(x=red))

Tags: powerbi, dax

What is the difference between `CALCULATE(m, x=red)` and `CALCULATE(m, KEEPFILTERS(x=red))`

Apparently they are not the same. I found docs and explanation but I still do not get it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/keepfilters-function-dax

https://dax.guide/keepfilters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is helpful to understand a bit more about how simple predicates in `CALCULATE` are evaluated. The following two expressions are equivalent; in fact, the first is just syntactic sugar for the second - the former is rewritten to the latter behind the scenes:

`CALCULATE ( [m], 'T'[Col] = "Red" )`

and

```
CALCULATE (
  [m],
  FILTER (
    ALL ( 'T'[Col] ),
    'T'[Col] = "Red"
  )
)
```

`FILTER` is an iterator that takes a table as its first argument and a predicate to be evaluated in row context as its second argument. It removes any rows from the input table where the predicate is false.

Thus, `CALCULATE` manipulation of filter context is actually almost entirely manipulations of tables. If you're comfortable with the relational algebra, the tables in args2-N of `CALCULATE` are tables which are left semijoined to the table(s) being operated on in the expression in `CALCULATE`'s arg1. These semijoins depend on relationships being defined in the data model.

So the pattern of `FILTER ( ALL ( 'T'[Col] ), <predicate> )` ignores any external filter context on 'T'[Col] and replaces that with a new filter context that you are defining.

Now for `KEEPFILTERS`. I am not 100% positive that this is just syntactic sugar, but I believe it is. Either way, the two expressions below are semantically equivalent - they will always return the same values:

`CALCULATE ( [M], KEEPFILTERS ( 'T'[Col] = "red" ) )`

and

```
CALCULATE (
  [M],
  FILTER (
    VALUES ( 'T'[Col] ), // this is the only difference from the first expansion
    'T'[Col] = "red"
  )
)
```

You can see that the `KEEPFILTERS` expansion is using `VALUES` instead of `ALL`. So, `ALL` returns all unique values from the named column, ignoring any filter context on that column (it also has other forms where it can operate on more than one column, but that is not relevant to this discussion). `VALUES` returns the unique values from the named column in the current filter context.

Another way to think of this is as follows. Assume that the value "red" does exist in 'T'[Col]. `FILTER ( ALL ( 'T'[Col] ), 'T'[Col] = "red" )` will always return the 1-column, 1-row table of 'T'[Col] with the value "red". `FILTER ( VALUES ( 'T'[Col] ), 'T'[Col] = "red" )` will always return a 1-column table, either with 0 or 1 row; if the external filter context includes 'T'[Col]="red", then it will return the 1-row table with 'T'[Col]="red", whereas if the external filter context does not include that value, it will return the empty table.

Again, the table output of the `FILTER` expressions above is treated as the right side table in a left semi-join.

Note, especially, that all of the above is based on single columns. You might get thrown for a loop if there are multiple columns contributing filter context. Here is an easy-to-understand example. We define two measures and put them into a table visual with 'DimDate'[Year] and 'DimDate'[Date].

```
Prior Date = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] ),
    'DimDate'[Date] = CurrentDate - 1
  )
```

```
Prior Day ALL DimDate = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] ),
    ALL ( 'DimDate' ),
    'DimDate'[Date] = CurrentDate - 1
  )
```

And here's what they return in our table visual:

[image: table with year and date and the two measures]

Arithmetic with dates is defined in DAX and `<date> - 1` will always return the prior date. So `CurrentDate - 1` on 2019-01-01 is 2018-12-31. But in our visual, we have filter context coming from both 'DimDate'[Year] and 'DimDate'[Date], so in the first measure, we're calculating `MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )` in the filter context of 'DimDate'[Year]=2019 and 'DimDate'[Date]=2018-12-31 (the context manipulation in our `CALCULATE`). There are no rows in 'DimDate' that simultaneously match both of those conditions, so the first version returns blank. The second version clears all filter context coming from 'DimDate', so the only context remaining is what we explicitly apply with `'DimDate'[Date] = CurrentDate - 1`.

Note that the example above would only return values for totals when we use `KEEPFILTERS`.

```
Prior Date KEEPFILTERS = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'DimDate'[Date] = CurrentDate - 1 )
  )
```

[image: KEEPFILTERS visual]

This only works on totals, because at a detail level, there is no way for `KEEPFILTERS ( 'DimDate'[Date] = CurrentDate - 1` to return any values. It's saying, essentially "find me a date that is one less than itself", which is obviously impossible. But at a grand total level, there are many dates in context, and so we're filtering a table of many contiguous dates. So our measure can return something for totals.

Answer (score 4):

Your first measure, without `KEEPFILTERS` overrides all other filters applied to field `x`.

The second measure, using `KEEPFILTERS` maintains the filter context on field `x`, and applies the new filter context as a subset of existing filters (or blank, if no overlap of filter contexts).

Here's a simple example PBIX file to demonstrate - play with the colour slicer, and see the difference in the two measures: https://pwrbi.com/so_57850298/

This [SQLBI.com article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-keepfilters-in-dax/) explains it well.

Comment: Thank you for file and links. So generally speaking `CALCULATE(m, x=red)` returns total for red for any color we slice the table. Whereas `KEEPFILTERS` returns total for red but produces results only for the red value (be it on the slicer or red color in table visual) and returns blanks for other colors.